What determines the orders of flats or sharps appearing on a key signature? Why is it not just top to bottom?
Backstory:
Beginner Piano player, self teaching, just trying to learn how to interpret key signatures
Problem:
Here I am puzzled:


This key signature details 6 notes to be flats.
The sequence left to right is not a strictly linear sequence going top to bottom.


Why is it not simply a descending order?
Could I write the signature in a descending order and have it still be valid?
Do identical signatures exist ( in that the same keys are flattened or sharped ) but where the order is changed?
For people learning, should I invest time to just visually memorize and become familiar with all signatures and their key? For example, should I just be able to see the above signature and immediately know by familiarity it is a G-Flat Major without having to intuit it?

Thanks.

The order follows the circle of fifths and is always the same, even though you may find differences in the vertical positioning due to using a different clef, and there are rare occurrences of uncommon key signatures that "skip" some sharps/flats. Visually memorizing may help (depending on how your memory better works) but, in reality, you should be learn the theory behind keys and the above circle of fifths.

You can't exactly intuit that it is G-flat major because E-flat minor has the same key signature.  Bonus answers: 1: see the suggested duplicate; 2: no; 3: no; 4: Eventually you should be able to identify a set of candidate keys (a major key and its relative minor) simply from the number of symbols in the signature, but there are tricks that rely on the standard ordering: for sharps, the major key is a minor second above the last one, and for flats the major key is the next-to-last one (or F if there's only one).

@Anon See what phoog suggested above, as there are many common "tricks" to find out the candidate keys (and possible related scales) based on the key signature, including: 1. visual count at a glance, if your "static memory" works well enough (normally reliable, but not 100% sure); 2. checking the "pitch" of each sharp/flat symbol; 3. mental shortcuts (check the last or next-to last symbol); 4. Eidetic memory (usually reliable as close as the sum of points 1, 2 and 3). In any case, the point remains: no matter what "trick" you may use, you must know the circle of fifths and how it works.

@phoog Honestly, compared to the duplicate, this question is just asked more cleanly, more comprehensively, with less presumption and foreknowledge, and with better formatting and grammar. Case in point: Why is these orders?

@Anon That post already gives the answer to your question. While I/we may agree that your post may have a more "canonical" presentation, the fact remains: the underlying theory is based on what that answer refers to (which is also mentioned in its very beginning): the theory behind the circle of fifths. That theory clearly explains the reasoning of those orders: it's F-C-G-D-A-E-B for sharps, and B-E-A-D-G-C-F (the exact opposite) for flats, and they all go by fifths, forward/clockwise/fifth-above (starting with F#) or backward/counterclockwise/fifth-below (starting with Bb) respectively.

Looks like you're well familiar with SE in general, and I imagine for most of them, the meta position is to avoid duplicates. There's the whole "community wiki" notion of consolidating frequent questions to put their "best foot forward" as it were, and maybe this is a good candidate for that. Meanwhile, the good news for future searchers is your question doesn't get deleted and will wind up in search results.

Also begs the question - why is the 3rd # (G#) not even in the stave..?

@Tim That's an interesting question. I recently asked myself about it, as there seem to be some level of convention of flat/sharp positioning depending on the clef, but, as far as I've been able to find out, it's not always logical. For instance, in Alto clef, A# (which could be shown above the stave), is actually shown below. I'm looking for related questions here on MSO, but I can't find one. I'll do some more research, but I'll eventually post a new question, as this always puzzled me.

@Tim Ok, it already exists, obviously ;-) Why is the G flat major key signature written with a flat on the lower G and not the higher one? confirms that positioning is logical to a certain length, then it's just convention/tradition. Still, I find it quite annoying, as it's not always consistent and it doesn't follow immediate logic concepts (including hierarchical ones). In any case, sharps are the most inconsistent ones, especially for rare clefs. I've added a further answer to show some differences.

Several people have mentioned the circle of fifth already, but I think there's still potential to showcase how versatile that thing is.
Here is one from 
As people have already mentioned if you want to draw that you basically just have to remember the sequence F C G D A E B (the next in line being the fifth to the former) or in the other direction B E A D G C F you'd get the circle of fourths. After that the pattern just repeats with sharps so F♯ C♯ G♯ D♯ A♯ E♯ B♯ and after that F## or rather F C and so on, while before it also repeats just with flats F♭ C♭ G♭ D♭ A♭ E♭ B♭ (F).
So with respect to the key signatures all you need now is a starting point. For example C major or A minor, which are fairly commonly known to not have sharps or flats. Now if you go from there to your preferred key signature you just need to count the number of steps. In clockwise direction you'd add sharps in counterclockwise direction you add flats. Which sharps and flats? Well the same sequence as before. You start with the F♯ then C♯ then G♯ and so on. Now if you start from a key that already has a sharp or flat in their signature than adding a flat or sharp means that they cancel essentially sharp = +1 flat =-1 so what remains is again the number of sharps or flats that follow the familiar sequence.
While for flats you'd follow the same sequence in the opposite direction. So the first flat would be B than E than A than D then G then C then F. How they are notated on the staff is probably more of a convenience thing, the 1st sharp/flat is obvious the next is a fifth/fourth up while trying to keep it on the staff.
Also the key corresponding to the key signature can usually seen by the last sign. So for sharps it's a semitone above for major or two below for minor. While for flats you can look at the second to last sign, which for B♭ major is B♭ and for E♭ is E♭ and so on. Which doesn't work for C and F, but they are common enough to be remembered on their own.


The order of the sharps and flats has to do with the order in which they appear in the various keys. The key of one sharp is G major (or E minor), which has F#, and every other key containing sharps contains F#, so that's the first sharp in all key signatures.

The key of two sharps is D major (or B minor), which includes F# and C#, and all keys with three or more sharps include those two, so they're the first two sharps listed.
The key of three sharps is A major (or F# minor), which inclues F#, C#, and G#, and all keys with four or more sharps include those three.
And so on.

Yes. It would look strange to an experienced musician, but they could be written in any order and still have the same meaning.

Order has no impact. Every key signature is unique to its major/minor keys (plus associated modes).

Either through concerted effort or by repeated exposure, one should know at a glance what major and minor keys are represented by each key signature. Because the ordering is canonical, all you have to know is how many sharps or flats there are — one doesn't need to check which notes have sharps or flats each time, since that doesn't change. The key of four sharps (E major / C# minor) is the same (F# C# G# D#) no matter the order they appear.



4: ... Except for some modern/experimental/avant-garde/folk music with non-standard scales.


that depends on the visual/mental capabilities and their associations. While most experienced "normal" people would just count the amount, that may not be true for people with different visual capabilities or mental references. For instance, a screen reader or OCR may misunderstand if the order was "unnatural" or even skips some steps in the fifths. The assumption is based on the circle of fifths and possible verification of the contents, including the order (for instance, in case of handwriting). I realize that these are "fringe" cases, but it still has to be considered to some extent.


@musicamante Fair enough, but the development of the canonical order of sharps and flats occurred long before screen readers or OCRs.

@Aaron You're completely right. Though, who wrote the implementation of those OCRs, and based on what principles if not their own? On what data relation are the current AI models based? Order has no impact as much as the readers' capabilities are able to help them with it. It's logical to assume that old OCR based software as much as newer AI based implementations would fail just as much as a human would; in fact, considering the current state of AIs, they'd fail even more due to hallucinations, lack of context awareness and no proper logical reasoning. We just call it "intelligence".

@musicamante I guess I've lost track of the point you're making. The key signature's meaning doesn't change if the order of the sharps/flats change. Are you saying different orders mean different keys?

@Aaron I'm saying that if the signature is written in the wrong order, one may not read the correct key, for instance because they're used to check the last flat/sharp (and there are enough to discourage counting). Or even considering cases of skipped signatures (I can think of that famous piece in Microkosmos) and, why not, simple typo in handwriting.

@Anon One trivia-type warning: Some old sources put the accidentals in multiple octaves. See p 10 of this (large) pdf of Bach's violin sonatas & partitas, a D major with two F sharps: https://vmirror.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/2/25/IMSLP150643-PMLP04292-BWV_1001_-1006(D_B_Mus._ms._Bach_P_967).pdf

The order of the accidentals follows the circle of fifths. This is by no means an accident. If you consider a major scale such as

C D E F G A B C
 W W S W W W S

we can ask: What is the smallest change required to get different major scale? It is easy to see that this happens exactly if we move the first semitone one degree up (raising the 4th) or the second one one step down (lowering the 7th). This gives the major scale on the 5th (G major) or on the 4th (F major).
If we repeat this you automatically get the circle of fifths. If you consider the pair of current key and new key in order of circles of fifths the changed accidental is always the 4th of the lower one and the 7th of the upper one. This means that there is a simple shift of one position between key and accidental — when going down this is simply one position of the new key (C→F: add Bb, F→Bb: add Eb, ..., the same way D→G: add C, G→C: add F), when going up this is 2 positions down and 7 positions up (as we raise by a halfstep), so 5 positions up of the new key (C→G: add F♯, G→D: add C♯, ..., the same way Bb→F: add E, F→C: add B). So if we map the characteristic accidental to the keys we get:

      key: ... - Ab- Eb- Bb- F - C - G - D - A - E - ...
acc. down: ... - Db- Ab- Ab- Bb- F - C - G - D - A - ...
  acc. up: ... - G - D - A - E - B - F♯- C♯- G♯- D♯- ...

So this is where this ordering comes from. One particular side effects of this is that the last accidental printed is the most significant one — any standard key signature including this one will by necessity also include the other ones.
This means experienced musicians do not need to count accidentals to figure out keys. They just need to look at the last accidentals, and know that all previous accidentals are included. This makes picking up the key much easier. Consider these alternative ways of notating Gb major and Db major:

With conventional notation it is quite easy to pick out the relevant information. With other orderings ... not so much.

Good explanation, but note that sharps&flats in the key signature are generally not called "accidentals" as this term conventionally refers specifically to sharps etc that are not in the current key signature.

@psmears Okay, in German we use it that way (accidental → Vorzeichen, key → Generalvorzeichen). What would then be the correct term here?

@Lazy Apparently Vorzeichen and Generalvorzeichen https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorzeichen_(Musik) Though Vorzeichen doesn't have the connoation of "accidental" (being an accident to a rule), but already just expresses that it's a sign coming in front of a note.

@Lazy I'm not aware of a specific general term - I've usually just seen variations on "sharps and flats" (as used for example in the Wikipedia page on key signatures though someone here might know more than me!

@psmears Hm, how about adapting the french term and say “alteration”? Would that make sense? Else I see your point, but considering there does not appear any alternative term I would still phrase it like that. But I would like to get rid of those stupid fretboard diagrams. Seriously, who thought it was a good idea to do this?

@Lazy: I don't think "alteration" would be understood by most people. The trouble with using "accidental" is that to people who know something about the topic already it gives the impression you don't know what you're talking about, and to people who don't it encourages them to use the wrong word. (Can't help with the fretboard diagrams, no idea what that's all about!)

@psmears As I said, if there is a correct word, then enlighten me. If there isn’t I take this as a flaw in the English language, and use the best thing there is that people will understand, which to me would seem to be “Accidental”. I do not care what people think of me who are so superficial to measure knowledge by choice of words in some language in an international world where this language is spoken natively by mere 5% of the population. And about encouraging the wrong word — that would make sense as long as there is a correct word. If you tell me I will encourage people to use it.

@lazy: The topic of special names for the accidentals in key signatures is discussed in this question and its answers.

@Lazy: The correct terminology is "sharps and flats"; that would be my recommendation. It's not really a deficiency in the language; it's hardly uncommon for English to use more than one word where German uses just one, languages are just different :)

@psmears, Lazy: I've settled on "key-signature sign" (or "key-signature symbol") -- a bit cumbersome, perhaps, but accurate and precise.
It is certainly less cumbersome than any translation I can come up with that is more precise than "the reader" for der Vorleser.

@psmears So do microtonal key signatures not exist? Actually I can make a good point for refering to the signs in the key signature collectively as “accidentals”: The term “Accidental” in music is quite a bit older than the practice of key signatures. Key signatures developed from a pracise to keep accidentals at the beginning of the piece for the whole piece to avoid having to write them out so often. Basically accidentals that are pinned to the beginning.

@psmears Then one could make a point that sharps, flats, naturals can be accidental, but that the collective term accidentals does not actually make sense. But if we use accidentals als a colloquialism for accidental symbols, then surely it would also make sense for symbols in the key signature.
But what you are giving is not using two words where German (or any other language) would use one. It is avoid a collective term by using a list all possibilities. Such as not saying “pitch class” or whatever, but a, a♯, b, c, c♯, d, d♯, e, f, f♯, g and g♯.

@phoog But is it more precise than key signature accidental? I think with that even if you debate if the use is correct there is little ambiguity. Every musician will know what I talk about. If I say key signature sign/symbol — then what do I mean? Could also mean the symbol that is used for the whole time signature. Also I am not the only one who uses accidental in this context. For one thing this meaning of accidental wrt. the key signature is used in the manuals for Finale, Sibelius, Dorico, MuseScore, Lilypond ... So to me this feels like a bit of an ideological debate.

@Lazy: I didn't make up the language; I'm just trying to let you know how things are - don't shoot the messenger! "Accidentals", today, is generally understood by most people to mean "signs showing there is a temporary change from the key signature". I believe your answer would be better, and better received, if you were to follow standard terminology - whatever the merits or otherwise of how that terminology works. But you are free to do with that information what you will :)

@psmears I will gladly embrace the standard terminology if anyone can actually tell what the standard terminology is. If there isn’t any — how am I supposed to use it. I’m not shooting the messenger, I’m simply asking you to properly back up your critique. Also as I pointed out in the reply to phoog this terminology is not that esoteric when things get technical. I’ve found this use of accidental in the manuals for Finale, Sibelius, Dorico, MuseScore and Lilypond. So the people behind these find this use acceptable. You do not. Are you sure that your position is one of absolute truth?

I've given you a link to the dictionary (here's another ); I've linked to the relevant Wikipedia article. I've told you what terminology is used ("sharps & flats"). I'm not sure what more I can do at this point!

As I have already said sharps and flats is by no means a collective noun, but simply a list. “The position of the sharps and flats in the key signature depend on whether they are sharps or flats” sounds quite stupid compared to something like “the position of the accidentals in the key signature depend on ...”. Also I have pointed out how other people with at least some authority in notation use the term this way. So what can you do? Either give a good, commonly understood alternative, or stop trying to zealously push your opinion of how these terms should be used on other people.

There are a number of suggestions at https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/collective-word-for-sharps-and-flats-in-the-key-signature.

@Peter Suggestions I’ve seen there are essentials, incidentals and plain symbols. The last is too unspecific to be useful in many cases, the other ones are obscure. Do not know if these are real options are just funny stuff collected on the way.

@Lazy, I suggested Essentials because I found it in a reference book. I have never heard it used "in the wild" though.

The order of the flats in a key signature is always BEADGCF. To determine what key it is, look at the flat that's second from the right. In your example that's G, so the key is G-flat major. With only two flats (BE), the key would be B-flat major. With three flats (BEA), E-flat major. etc.
Similarly with sharps; their order is just the opposite: FCGDAEB. I don't remember the heuristic for figuring out the key with sharps. :-(

Half step up from the final sharp listed.

BEADGCF Any tips on how to remember that sequence?

@Anon the circle of fifths.

@Anon Easy... it's FCGDAEB backwards :-)

@Anon Or, skip every two letters: BcdEfgAbcD... etc.

One mnemonic for the order of sharps is Father Christmas Goes Down All Escalators Backwards.  Or Fat Children Get Diabetes after Eating Bacon.  Which goes rather nicely with the one for spaces of the bass clef: All Cows Eat Grass.   Or the terrible warning: Anal Congress Encourages Gonorrhea.

Father Christmas Gave Dad An Electric Blanket ----- Blanket Exploded And Dad Got Cold Feet.

If you are familiar with the circle of 5ths, the way sharps and flats are added is actually quite easy and simple. They are added in the order of the circle, or in 5ths.
F is one flat, B
Bb is two flats, B,E
Eb is three flats, B,E,A
Each new flattened note is a 5th lower (or a 4th higher) than the previous one.
Skipping ahead to your example, Gb has 6 flats and they are B,E,A,D,G,C, which is the circle of 5ths starting on B going counter clockwise.
Sharps work in the same way, but in the opposite direction. Take the key of F# or 6 sharps. The sharped notes are F,C,G,D,A,E, which is also the circle of 5ths starting on F but moving clockwise.
Bottom line, flats are added counter clockwise and sharps are added clockwise. Flat keys increase in accidentals counter clockwise and sharps increase clockwise. In both cases the accidentals are added in 5ths, up for sharp keys and down 5ths for flat keys. Pretty logical if you think about it.
As for how all the key signatures are written, Since up a 5th is the same as down a 4th, a system of alternating them is the way sharps and flats are added. Look at Gb in your question or any circle of 5ths chart. You will see it starts with Bb then goes up a 4th, down a 5th and continues alternating that way. Sharp keys start down a 4th, up a 5th, down a 4th twice then alternate up, down, etc. Fun fact, the new accidental in every flat key creates the perfect 4th and in every sharp key creates the major 7th, or leading tone.
DISCLAIMER: This does not take into account unconventional key signatures.

Playing in several bands, the number of sharps was shown by the bandleaders by fingers. Up for sharps, down for flats. Thus, four fingers up would indicate E/C♯m, 3 down, E♭/Cm.
We also often had sheet music written by someone who simply put the sharps/flats any old where. It didn't matter. We knew instinctively what key was meant by the number rather than where they where placed, as that placement would always be the same in 'proper' music! So it really didn't matter much!
Convention is the accepted form, and we get used to counting how many rather than whichthey are.

How did the bandleader indicate C major or A minor with fingers? :)

That's a question I posed many years ago - no good answers yet! But from memory, the key for the following song always seemed to be a major one!! So it was easy to segue into it, often via ii>V>I

To put it simply:
It's the order in which they appear if you consider the signature with one flat/sharp first, then the one with two, then the one with three, and so on.
One flat: F major, contains Bb.
Two flats: Bb major, contains Bb and Eb.
Three flats: Eb major, contains Bb, Eb, Ab.
And so on.
So you write the signature as they're added: Bb, then Eb, then Ab, then Db...
